# verificação no método settter - java

Tags: java, getters-setters

Estou fazendo um exercício em java que pede para calcular a área de um retângulo, se o usurário digitar algum numero menor ou igual que "0.0" deve aparecer uma mensagem de erro, porém essa verificação deve ser feita no método settter. Isso é possível? Se sim como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer esse tipo de verificação no método set

```
public void setValor(double valor) {
    if(valor > 0.0) {
         this.valor = valor;
    }

    else {
        // Mensagem de erro aqui
    }
}
```